# using shared_ptr to std::vector in range-based for loop

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, ranged-loops

I wrote a c++ function that assembles some data then then returns a `std::shared_ptr` to a newly allocated `std::vector` containing the data. Something analogous to this:

```
std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int>> shared_ptr_to_std_vector_of_ints()
{
    auto v = std::make_shared<std::vector<int>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) v->push_back(i);
    return v;
}
```

I tried to iterate over the contents of the vector using a range-based for loop, but it acted as if the vector was empty. After fiddling around, I found I could get it to behave as I expected by assigning the value returned from the function to a local variable, then referencing that in the loop:

```
// Executes loop zero times:
std::cout << "First loop:" << std::endl;
for (int i : *shared_ptr_to_std_vector_of_ints()) std::cout << i << std::endl;

// Prints three lines, as expected
std::cout << "Second loop:" << std::endl;
auto temp = shared_ptr_to_std_vector_of_ints();
for (int i : *temp) std::cout << i << std::endl;
```

That snipped prints this:

```
First loop:
Second loop:
1
2
3
```

Why does the first version not work?

I’m using Xcode on macOS Sierra 10.12.6. I believe it is using LLVM 9.0 to compile the c++ code.

Comment: Do you really need `shared_ptr` around `std::vector` (as `std::vector` already manage memory) ? (especially true with provided usage).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that `shared_ptr_to_std_vector_of_ints` returns by-value, so what it returns is a temporary.

The [range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) is equivalent to

```
{
  init-statement
  auto && __range = range_expression ; 
  auto __begin = begin_expr ;
  auto __end = end_expr ;
  for ( ; __begin != __end; ++__begin) { 
    range_declaration = *__begin; 
    loop_statement 
  } 
}
```

The part `auto && __range = range_expression ;`, for your example it will be `auto && __range = *shared_ptr_to_std_vector_of_ints() ;`. `shared_ptr_to_std_vector_of_ints` returns a temporary `std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int>>`, then dereference on it to get the `std::vector<int>`, then bind it to the rvalue-reference `__range`. The temporary `std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int>>` will be destroyed after the full expression, and `use_count` decreases to 0 so the `std::vector<int>` being managed is destroyed too. Then `__range` becomes dangled reference. After that e.g. `auto __begin = begin_expr ;` would try to get the iterator from `__range`, which leads to UB.

(emphasis mine)

> If range_expression returns a temporary, its lifetime is extended until the end of the loop, as indicated by binding to the rvalue reference `__range`, but **beware that the lifetime of any temporary within range_expression is not extended.**

As your 2nd version showed, the issue could be solved via using a named variable instead; or you can also use init-statement (from C++20):

```
for (auto temp = shared_ptr_to_std_vector_of_ints(); int i : *temp) std::cout << i << std::endl;
```

Comment: Or without extra name, create a temporary: `for (int i : std::vector<int>(*shared_ptr_to_std_vector_of_ints()))`.